# Not able to access web-app folder files in Grails 3

Tags: grails, grails-3.0, grails-3.1

I am not able to access web-app folder files in Grails 3.
I have `robots.txt` in the web-app folder and in Grails 2 I was able to access it directly at `http://localhost:8080/robots.txt`. After migrating to Grails 3 I am not able to access it anymore at `http://localhost:8080/robots.txt`.

How can I make these files accessible again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See https://github.com/grails/grails-core/releases/tag/v3.0.12 and part `Location of static resources`

In Grails 3 you can store your files under src/main/resources. You can access them by filename preceded with `static` for example `http://localhost:8080/static/robots.txt`.

This path can be changed using config option as defined in attached URL

Comment: I can't make it work with this, did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem in Grails 3.3.1. I had the necessity to access a file template to use it with a plugin (excel-export plugin). After reading the documentation, I put the file under src/main/resources. It worked with OK in development mode (grails run-app), but I received an error in production environment (grails war). After a lot of reading, I've found the way to make it work. I've let the file in the same directory (src/main/resources), and then, in my controller:

```
def template = this.class.classLoader.getResource('myExcelFile.xlsx')
def path = template.file  //will give you the real path to your file
```

Having the path, you can then open a stream or do what you need to do. In my case, use it whith the plugin:

```
new WebXlsxExporter(path).with {
  setResponseHeaders(response)
    add(products, withProperties)
    save(response.outputStream)
}
```